# Single byte XOR cipher cpp

Tags: c++, cryptography

I am supposed to decipher a hexadecimal string using a character. I ran a loop for every char(0-255) and got myself a vector of these strings. Now, I'm trying to apply etaoin shrdlu method to get the best frequency of letters in the string such that I don't have to check manually for the right deciphered string. I am pasting my code, the code is compiling but is not printing anything.
If anyone could help

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


int hexchartoint(char hex){

    hex=tolower(int(hex));

    if(hex>='0' && hex<='9')
        return hex-'0';
    if(hex>='a' && hex<='f')
        return hex-'a'+10;
}

unordered_map<char,int> counter(string s){

    unordered_map<char,int> ma;
    for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
        ma[s[i]]++;
}



int main(){

    string s;
    cin>>s;


    //unordered_map<char,int> ma;


    vector<pair<char,float>> etaoin;

    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('a',8.24));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('b',1.50));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('c',2.80));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('d',4.29));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('e',12.81));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('f',2.25));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('g',2.03));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('h',6.15));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('i',6.15));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('j',0.15));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('k',0.78));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('l',4.06));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('m',2.43));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('n',6.80));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('o',7.58));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('p',1.94));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('q',0.09));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('r',6.04));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('s',6.38));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('t',9.13));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('u',2.78));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('v',0.98));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('w',2.38));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('x',0.15));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('y',1.99));
    etaoin.push_back(make_pair('z',0.07));


    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
        v.push_back(hexchartoint(s[i]));

    vector<int> pairs;
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i+=2)
        pairs.push_back(v[i]*16 + v[i+1]);

    vector<string> fin;
    string z="";
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
        //vector<string> fin1;

        for(int j=0;j<pairs.size();j++){
            pairs[j]^=i;
            z+=pairs[j];
            //ma[pairs[j]]++;
        }
        fin.push_back(z);
        z="";

    }

    /*for(int i=0;i<fin.size();i++){
        cout<<fin[i]<<endl;
    }*/


    float fittingQuotient=INT_MAX;
    string answer="";

    for(int i=0;i<fin.size();i++){
        int len=fin[i].length();
        unordered_map<char,int> inside1=counter(fin[i]);
        unordered_map<char,float> inside2;

        for(int i=0;i<=25;i++){
            if(inside1[i+'a']!=0){
                inside2[i+'a']=(int(i+'a')*100)/len;
                //inside1[i]=INT_MAX;
            }
        }

        float temp=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=25;i++){
                //float a=etaoin[i+'a'];float b=inside2[i+'a'];
            temp+=etaoin[i].second - inside2[i+'a'];
        }
        temp/=inside1.size();

        if(temp<fittingQuotient){
            fittingQuotient=temp;
            answer=fin[i];
        }

    }


    cout<<answer<<endl;








    return 0;



}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is multitude of problems with your code, and the way you posted it here does not make it easy to identify them all.

Main problem and probably the cause of your issue is that `counter(string s)` never returns the map you build inside:

```
unordered_map<char,int> counter(string s){
    unordered_map<char,int> ma;
    for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
        ma[s[i]]++;

    return ma; // <- this was missing
}
```

There is similar problem with `hexchartoint(char hex)`, which does not return a value for incorrect input.

**Non-void function have to return a value in all control paths, otherwise you run into undefined behavior.**

Another thing is that you would never run into this kind of trouble if you would turn on compiler warnings. How you do it depends on the compiler, for gcc typical flags would be `-Wall -Wextra`